# Install from file containing output from apt list --installed

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management

I have a file that contains the output of `apt list --installed` from another machine.

i.e.

```
accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas/focal,focal,now 0.0.7+17.10.20170922-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
accountsservice/focal-updates,focal-security,now 0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
acl/focal,now 2.2.53-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

...and so on.

Is there an easy way to install these packages using the aforementioned file and the command line?

Comment: Are you looking to install those specific versions?

Comment: @muru That is a good question. As long as everything in the list of packages has its dependencies taken care of, then I am fine if the versions are the same or newer. (As-is, it can be assumed that dependencies are taken care of.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extract the part before the first `/` and use that with `xargs` to install via `apt`:

```
xargs -a <(awk -F/ '{print $1}' some-file) apt install
```

Or:

```
awk -F/ '{print $1}' some-file | xargs apt install -y
```

Answer (score 6):

APT clearly states that is not designed to use with scripts:

> **SCRIPT USAGE AND DIFFERENCES FROM OTHER APT TOOLS**
> The [**apt**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt.8.html)(8) commandline is designed as an end-user tool and it may change behavior between versions. While it tries not to break backward compatibility this is not guaranteed either if a change seems beneficial for interactive use.
>
> All features of [**apt**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt.8.html)(8) are available in dedicated APT tools like [**apt-get**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)(8) and [**apt-cache**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/aptcache.8.html)(8) as well.  [**apt**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt.8.html)(8) just changes the default value of some options (see [**apt.conf**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html)(5) and specifically the Binary scope). So you should prefer using these commands (potentially        with some additional options enabled) in your scripts as they keep backward compatibility as much as possible.

You are using wrong tool. Better way is to use `dpkg` itself:

```
dpkg -l | awk '$1 == "ii" {print $2}' > installed
sudo apt-get install $(cat installed)
```

Details:

- `man apt` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt.8.html#script%20usage%20and%20differences%20from%20other%20apt%20tools);
- `man dpkg` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg.1.html).

By the way this method looks narrow-minded (like in this great guide [on Community](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/creating-a-software-bill-of-materials-sbom/25519)). You are loosing big amount of information - package origins and their GPG keys.
Moreover this method will fail on the first occurrence of locally installed package or the package installed from some PPA which does not exist on second machine.

---

If you want all-inclusive service - try my [python script](https://github.com/N0rbert/srslsud) named `srslsud` (Save/Restore Software List Script for Ubuntu and Debian).
It will save all APT repositories, their GPG keys; lists of Snaps, Flatpaks and Ubuntu Make apps to JSON files from the first machine.
Then you can restore this list using same JSON files on the second machine.

Comment: I love how you say using `apt` isn't intended for direct machine parsing, and then you use a `dpkg` invocation that requires two filter steps before it can be parsed :P - Have you considered `dpkg --get-selections` / `dpkg --set-selections`?

Comment: I went with apt to get around errors in the case of already installed packages. I couldn't remember if running `dpkg` directly in these instances will error or not, but I knew for sure that apt would just ignore them. Honestly, the Apt warning has never made sense to me. They complain that updates may break current implementations, but that is true of any software. It is the whole reason for our `X.X.XX` versioning system, distinguishing between breaking and non-breaking changes.

Comment: @NateT output from `apt` is locale-sensitive.

Comment: @bac0n I see. That makes sense then. Good to know. Is the locale-based functionality baked into the apt-get logic, or just the interface?

Answer (score 1):

I actually recently wrote a script on my own machine that, at its core, does exactly that. I does it by first piping to `sed 's/\/.*//g'` to remove everything after the slash. Then the output is piped to `xargs /usr/bin/sudo apt install`.

As @N0rbert mentioned of his/her solution, the main weakness here is that it takes only one error case (such as a missing repo in `sources.list`) to halt the entire operation. Therefore, if you are using a different sources file than the system that generated the input, the solution that you go with will need to first check that the pkg is available to your system. In general, your choice will depend on your the intended use-case(s).

For example, you could probably get away without piping through `sed`, but in my case, the script uses tee to save the list to a file, and then does further processing using the file as input. In fact, the list itself is the central theme of that script and a few others that work in tandem with it.

A couple notes: You do not need to worry about checking whether or not the package is already installed on your machine. If it is, apt will simply skip it over. Also, since you are most likely about to install quite a few packages when running, It is a good idea to start out with the `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` command. This will save you from downloading a bunch of packages just to end up downloading a slightly newer version for many of them a bit later.